# How to extract data from IE following submission

Tags: excel, vba

Very new to VBA...

I'm attempting to bring in the resulting tract code for an address submitted to the FFIEC geocoding website using VBA in excel.

I've tried using the code below but I can't get it to bring in the answer of 8391.00 is this example

```vb
Sub fillwebform()

    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Navigate "https://geomap.ffiec.gov/FFIECGeocMap/GeocodeMap1.aspx"
    IE.Visible = True

    IE.Width = 1200
    IE.Height = 800
   'IE.FullScreen = True

    While IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

    IE.Document.getElementById("Address").Value = "121 N LaSalle St, Chicago, IL 60602"
    IE.Document.getElementById("btnSearch_label").Click

    While IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend


    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    Set Doc = IE.Document
    Dim sDD

    sDD = Doc.getElementById("TractCode").innerText & "is the tract code"

    MsgBox sDD


End Sub
```

The tract code returned is just blank in my code

Comment: Try this line before declaring the Doc variable `Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Sub GetTractCode()
Dim url As String, body As String, code As String

With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    url = "https://geomap.ffiec.gov/FFIECGeocMap/GeocodeMap1.aspx/GetGeocodeData"
    body = "{""sSingleLine"": ""121 N LaSalle St, Chicago, IL 60602"", ""iCensusYear"": ""2019""}"

    .Open "POST", url, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    .send body

    code = Split(.responseText, """sTractCode"":""")(1)
    code = Trim(Split(code, """,""")(0)) & " Is The Tract Code"
End With

MsgBox code
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a more flexible approach, which is faster and cleaner:

```
Option Explicit

Sub geomap()
Dim req As New WinHttpRequest
Dim jsonResponse As Object
Dim jsonRequest As Object
Dim reqBody As String
Dim searchQuery As String
Dim searchYear As String
Dim json As String
Dim url As String
url = "https://geomap.ffiec.gov/FFIECGeocMap/GeocodeMap1.aspx/GetGeocodeData"
json = "{""sSingleLine"": """", ""iCensusYear"": """"}"
searchQuery = "121 N LaSalle St, Chicago, IL 60602"
searchYear = "2019"
Set jsonRequest = JsonConverter.ParseJson(json)
jsonRequest("sSingleLine") = searchQuery
jsonRequest("iCensusYear") = searchYear
reqBody = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(jsonRequest)
With req
    .Open "POST", url, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    .send reqBody
    Set jsonResponse = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
End With
Debug.Print jsonResponse("d")("sTractCode")
End Sub
```

For this you will need a [JSON Parser](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON). Follow the instructions in the link to import the parser into your project. You will also need the following references (VB Editor>Tools>References):

1. Microsoft Scripting Runtime
2. Microsoft WinHTTP Services Version 5.1